Write a JSON file from a Dataframe in Pola-rs
Starting with a DataFrame that has a form such as this
df = pl.DataFrame([{"SkuId":1}])
shape: (1, 1)
┌───────┐
│ SkuId │
│ ---   │
│ i64   │
╞═══════╡
│ 1     │
└───────┘

How can I write it to a JSON file with this format?
"SkuId": {"source": 1},  


Can you show the full actual output you expect for the example? As it stands, "SkuId": {"source": 1}, is not valid JSON.

Polars has two (really 3) nested types. There are Structs which are like objects (aka {}) in JSON and Lists which are like Arrays (aka []).
To get it to put JSON in the format you're looking for, you need to make a struct.
df.select(SkuId=pl.struct(source=pl.col('SkuId'))).write_json()

[{"SkuId":{"source":1}}]

Of course, if you put a file path inside write_json() then it'll write it to the file instead of just printing it to stdout.
